# Picklist Dependencies lost when Managed Package Upgrade Installed

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, field-dependencies

Whenever we install a new version of our managed package in a client's org, we are losing the field dependencies that the client specifies locally for a managed package object.

Is this expected behaviour?  The [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/packaging_component_behavior.htm) seem to suggest otherwise:

> Field Dependencies
> Developers and subscribers can add, change, or
> remove field dependencies.
>
> If the developer adds a field dependency,
> it is added during installation unless the subscriber has already
> specified a dependency for the same field.
>
> If a developer removes a dependency, this change is not reflected in the
> subscriber's organization during an upgrade.
>
> If the developer introduces a new
> picklist value mapping between the dependent and controlling fields,
> the mapping is added during an upgrade.
>
> If a developer removes a
> picklist value mapping, the change is not reflected in the
> subscriber’s organization during an upgrade.

Edit: to clarify, this is picklist value dependencies we're talking about, not whether one field relies on another or not.

Comment: Please confirm that you are upgrading the managed package rather than uninstalling and re-installing.

Comment: This is correct

Comment: @GeorgeS. were you able to solve this?

Comment: @OlesMalkov I don't believe so, just worked around it.